# D3 zoomable yAxis in hours

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to figure out how to make a zoomable y axis that is in hours. I want the y axis to range from 7AM to 5PM. My x axis in days.

Currently, I have the y axis in hours but it only shows 12AM at the top of the y axis. I am unsure of where to get it to go from 7AM to 5PM. My code does zoom on both of the axis.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
// Define the min and max date 
var mindate = new Date(2013,0,20),  // TODO: clip date 
    maxdate = new Date(2013,0,25);

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([mindate, maxdate])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([mindate, maxdate])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%A : %d")); // d is for testing 

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 12)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%I %p")); // For 12 hour time 

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    // .x(x)
    .y(y)
   .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

svg.append("rect")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

function zoomed() {
     svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
     svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after, but I've interpreted your question as how to create a scale from 7am to 5pm on the same day with 1 hour steps.  The first thing was to create a set of dates for the y-scale for the required time as in:

```
var ymindate = new Date(2013,0,20, 7),  // TODO: clip date 
    ymaxdate = new Date(2013,0,20, 17);
```

The next step required only minor changes to your code.  the ticks were set to d3.time.hours not days and the step was set to 1 hour, as shown below.

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 1)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%I %p"));
```

If you want just 7am and 5pm to appear on multiple days you would have to create a custom set of ticks and use a time intervals

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. I was missing the .ticks(d3.time.hours, 1) part.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the domain of the y scale accordingly. At the moment, your min and max dates are both full days, so you get only one value for the time. If you used for example

```
var mindate = new Date(2013,0,20, 7, 0, 0, 0),
    maxdate = new Date(2013,0,25, 17, 0, 0, 0);
```

you should get the times you want on the y axis.

Comment: When I tried that nothing changed. It is still showing just 12AM.

Comment: Oh, you also need to change your ticks definition to something like `.ticks(d3.time.hour, 1)`. Or you can omit that completely.